# How to fix the width of a flexbox item

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I want to add a responsive page that contains many cards of different widths , for example I want the first card have 520px, the second 300px etc.. but when I open them from mobile or and device it should be responsive
someone advice me to use flexbox to be responsive but I use it and I don't Know how to responsive using it , I want to build a responsive page with css3 should I use flexbox ?

when I minimise the browser there's no responsive page with this code :

```css
#container-target {
  position: relative;
  background-color:#eeeeee; 
  max-width:590px;
  height:140px;
  border-radius:5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.target {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.button {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#container-target .title {
  background-color:#111f35;
  color:white;
  height:35px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <title>Template</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="container-target">

      <div class="title">

        CIBLAGE

      </div>

      <div class="body-target">

        <p>Envoyer à tout le monde ou cibler des utilisateurs.</p> 

        <div class="target">

            <div class="radio">

                <input type="radio" name="radio" />Tout le monde

              </div>

              <div class="button">

                <button>Créer un ciblage</button>

              </div>

        </div>


      </div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Flexbox could be a way. For your problem, could you please add [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: flexbox is really usefull for making something responsive yes, but if you have fixed width and height, @media rules might help aswell

Comment: Yeah its really simple to do. There are frameworks that have this code pre-build like bootstrap - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

An example of what you currently have will give you better feedback on this issue... but have you tried a percent of the screen instead of fixed pixels instead of using `520px` and `300px` use `width=63%` and `width=36%`.